# gnu C++ library stuck in loop during vector alloc

Tags: linux, gcc, gdb

Running linux kernel 3.6.6-1, gcc 4.7.2-2, the following program:

```
1 #include <vector>
2 using namespace std;
3 int main ()
4 {
5     vector<size_t> a (1 << 24);
6     return 0;
7 }
```

never returns from line 5.

when I run in gdb, I see that it is stuck in stl_algobase.h at line 743/744:

```
0x000000000040101c in std::__fill_n_a<unsigned long*, unsigned long, unsigned long> (__first=0x7fffeffd8060, __n=16777216, __value=@0x7fffffffe0a8: 0)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:743
740     __fill_n_a(_OutputIterator __first, _Size __n, const _Tp& __value)
741     {
742       const _Tp __tmp = __value;
743       for (__decltype(__n + 0) __niter = __n;
744        __niter > 0; --__niter, ++__first)
745     *__first = __tmp;
746       return __first;
747     }
```

__niter just stays at the value 1 and never counts down to 0.

This behavior only occurs after my system has been running for a while.  And when it occurs, the whole system seems borked.  That is, the gui soon stops responding, but I can ssh in and do some stuff, but eventually the whole system becomes unusable and I reboot.

After I reboot, the above program behaves as expected.

Obviously, the problem is not with my program.  It's just a symptom of some larger problem.

My question is: What do I do next?

I have checked all my error logs and found nothing.  I'm not getting hardware exceptions or anything like that, so it's hard to tell exactly when my system goes into this state.

I'm out of ideas, so any help would be very appreciated.

*edit:*

I changed my compiler options to `-g -Wall` and get the same result.

Here is the disassembly for __fill_n_a (with new options):

```
  1 0x00000000004010bd <+0>:    push   %rbp
  2 0x00000000004010be <+1>:    mov    %rsp,%rbp
  3 0x00000000004010c1 <+4>:    mov    %rdi,-0x18(%rbp)
  4 0x00000000004010c5 <+8>:    mov    %rsi,-0x20(%rbp)
  5 0x00000000004010c9 <+12>:   mov    %rdx,-0x28(%rbp)
  6 0x00000000004010cd <+16>:   mov    -0x28(%rbp),%rax
  7 0x00000000004010d1 <+20>:   mov    (%rax),%rax
  8 0x00000000004010d4 <+23>:   mov    %rax,-0x10(%rbp)
  9 0x00000000004010d8 <+27>:   mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
 10 0x00000000004010dc <+31>:   mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
 11 0x00000000004010e0 <+35>:   jmp    0x4010f7 <std::__fill_n_a<unsigned long*, unsigned long, unsigned long>(unsigned long*, unsigned long, unsigned long const&)+58>
 12 0x00000000004010e2 <+37>:   mov -0x18(%rbp),%rax
 13 0x00000000004010e6 <+41>:   mov -0x10(%rbp),%rdx
 14 0x00000000004010ea <+45>:   mov %rdx,(%rax)
 15 0x00000000004010ed <+48>:   subq $0x1,-0x8(%rbp)
 16 0x00000000004010f2 <+53>:   addq $0x8,-0x18(%rbp)
 17 0x00000000004010f7 <+58>:   cmpq $0x0,-0x8(%rbp)
 18 0x00000000004010fc <+63>:   setne  %al
 19 0x00000000004010ff <+66>:   test   %al,%al
 20 0x0000000000401101 <+68>:   jne    0x4010e2 <std::__fill_n_a<unsigned long*, unsigned long, unsigned long>(unsigned long*, unsigned long, unsigned long const&)+37>
 21 0x0000000000401103 <+70>:   mov -0x18(%rbp),%rax
 22 0x0000000000401107 <+74>:   pop %rbp
 23 0x0000000000401108 <+75>:   retq
```

I've also run my system's memory diagnostic tool with no errors and, as suggested by DL, ran memtest86 with no errors.

*edit:*

I have confirmed that this is not a hardware problem by running the same code on a different machine.  The other machine has the same kernel and compiler software installed, and it fails in the same way.

I am suspicious of ImageMagick.  This seems to occur only after I have run scripts that make a lot of ImageMagick convert calls.  I had problems with ImageMagick previously and had to set the shell variable MAGICK_THREAD_LIMIT=1.

Comment: what are your compiler flags?

Comment: Seems like a hardware problem, if it goes away after a reboot, then returns after some time. Maybe memtest ( http://www.memtest.org/ ) would be the place to start?

Comment: You should show assembly. Are you really sure it's "stuck at 1"? Maybe you're just going OOM somehow.

Comment: `-fopenmp -Wall -std=c++0x -g`

Comment: DL: I ran my system's full memory diagnostics and they all passed.  I will look into memtest too.

Comment: CDL: I'm pretty certain that I'm not out of memory.  My system monitor shows me at 10%.  Next time it crashes, I will post the assembly code.

Answer (score 2):

The overall symptoms you describe sound like running out of memory.  If the system memory use does not read as high, this may be due to some kind of RAM problem, as commenters have noted.

You say:

> __niter just stays at the value 1 and never counts down to 0.

but this doesn't quite make sense -- __niter should start as 16777216 and count down to 0.  If you were to break into this program randomly, it would almost certainly be in this loop, but the value of __niter would almost certainly not be 1 yet, and if you step through the loop it would seem to just loop.  I'm highly suspect of the debugging info put out by gcc 4.7 (actually, its a problem pretty much since gcc 4.0), in that gdb frequently seems to print out the wrong values for local variables, but if you inspect the code and look and memory/registers directly you can see the correct value.  If that's what is happening here, your problem probably has nothing to do with this program; its a system instability (possibly due to a hardware problem) that manifests as things hanging, such as this program.  Given what this program does, the hang probably occurs when it touches a previously untouched page (getting a page fault) and the kernel attempts to allocate a page.  Which suggests a memory problem, but you noted that you already ran memory diagnostics.  Also make sure that you don't have anything overclocked or otherwise running out of spec.

Comment: I should have said '__niter starts at 16777216, and counts down to 1, but never reaches 0.'  I determined this by setting a watch at __niter=N for successively lower values of N until it reached 1.  Then when __niter reached 1, I just step through the loop and see that __niter never gets decremented again.  But as you say, if gdb is not giving the correct value of __niter, or if the system is unstable, then this all means nothing.

Comment: How do I check to make sure that nothing is overclocking or running out of spec?